# Use excel VBA to update master list based on user input data

Tags: vba, excel

Background:

I have a single workbook with below sheets

- Master Worksheet: Column A is populated with account numbers
- multiple worksheets (13) that represent each account processor

Each day the Master worksheet and the processors sheets are populated with fresh accounts.

each worksheet Master, and 13 individuals processors has Columns A:F

As the processors work they update column F with status.  Column A in all worksheets is account number

All I want to do is have a VBA that Starts in A1 of the Master searches each cell (a1,a2,a3...) until there are no more account numbers against column A of the processors individual sheets, upon finding a match in respective column A's updates column F of the master based on the text in column F of the processors sheet

Its as simple as that.

I for some reason cannot wrap my head around this VBA stuff, all the examples are way more complex and I cant seem to make them work.

Feeling stressed with my first VBA outing and could really use some help

Comment: POST THE CODE YOU HAVE WRITTEN (WORKING OR NOT!).

Comment: I can in the morning but I am on my home PC now - will have to wait until I get to work

Comment: @Jeeped You're right this question looked off-topic for VBA code, my answer started with a formula that I thought "simple" but then OP said he already had it but wanted VBA. Well.... :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little ugly but you can do it with a formula like this, in `Master!F1`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor1!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor2!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor3!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor4!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor5!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor6!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor7!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor8!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor9!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor10!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor11!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor12!A:F,6,FALSE),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor13!A:F,6,FALSE),
    "")))))))))))))
```

Then copy/paste in column F of the master sheet.

**VBA**

Okay, so the chef wants it in VBA, probably because (s)he doesnt't want the formula to slow down working with the workbook. Well, I would do it in VBA by setting the formula for column `F` and then fixing the values.

```
Sub ColumnF()
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    With Worksheets("Master")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).offset(, 5)
            .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor1!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor2!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor3!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor4!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor5!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor6!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor7!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor8!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor9!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor10!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor11!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor12!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Processor13!A:F,6,FALSE)," & _
                """"")))))))))))))"

            .Value = .Value ' remove formula and freeze value
        End With
    End With
Cleanup:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This should be better and faster than looping in VBA on all cells of column A; first because it uses Excel's built-in capabilities instead of a VBA loop, second because it minimizes the exchange between VBA and Excel.

Comment: So This was my fix and how I was currently doing it.  It is ugly but it works.  I went into a meeting regarding the mathematical models I had built and one of the managers was very against this approach and told me to code it in VBA.

Comment: @mbillion I added the corresponding VBA with the same formula but freezinf the value. Please take into account the justification, I think it is better to use this working formula than to have a VBA loop.